# Can't sign in google play services with GoogleSignInOptions DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-games

When I set `GoogleSignInOptions` to `DEFAULT_SIGN_IN` everything is ok sign in success but when I try sign in with `GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN` returns `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}`.

Here is my code as written in developers.google docs

```
GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity,
GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4509). One possible reason is that the keystore SHA-1 was mismatched compared to the console. Try to check SHA-1 key (both release and debug), `applicationId` of build.gradle. Maybe something doesn't match with your console's setting.